# How to Pass header tag data when click on selected list in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events, javascript-objects

There is two list with name="ABC" in first list and name="XYZ" in second list.I want to get value of the selected list h4 tag using javascript by calling changefileinput() function?

For example:
if I Click on ABC List then I want to get value of its h4 tag i.e First
if I Click on XYZ List then I want to get value of its h4 tag i.e Second

```
    <!-Html Code ->
    <li>
    <a class="btn templateBtn d-flex mb-2" onclick="changefileinput(this);">
     <div class="ml-2">
       <h4 data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" name='ABC'>First</h4>
       <span>List Value-1</span>
     </div>
    </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a class="btn templateBtn d-flex mb-2" onclick="changefileinput(this);">
     <div class="ml-2">
       <h4 data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" name='XYZ'>Second</h4>
       <span>List Value-2</span>
     </div>
    </a>
    </li>
    
    <!-Javascript Code ->
    function changefileinput(el) {
      alert("Hello");
      console.log("Name of Selected List Element is:",
        el.name);
    }
```

Comment: If open with jquery answer you can use : `$(el).find("h4").text()`

Comment: or `el.querySelector("[data-toggle]").textContent`

Comment: @Swati here I think he means the value contained in `span`. `el.querySelector("h4 + span").textContent`

Comment: Not sure , in question it says `get value of its h4 tag..` :) @BOZ

Comment: ah yes, you might be right :) @Swati

Comment: I want to get h4 tag only of the list that has clicked

Comment: JsFiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/hemilshah/r1epumgn/15/

Comment: @HemilShah I can add a sample snippet if the comments weren't enough to solve the issue.